# Kotlin | Find param of a function which returns a lambda using the lambda

Tags: kotlin, lambda, kotlin-reflect

Say I have a function `haveFun` which takes in a `Method` (from `java.lang.reflect` package) as a param and returns a lambda as below

```
typealias AnyFun = (o: Any?) -> Any?

fun haveFun(method: Method): AnyFun {
    return { o -> method.invoke(o) }
}

data class Game(val name: String)
```

Now if I pass a method to the function and assign the lambda to a field as

```
val game = haveFun(Game::name.javaGetter!!)
```

Can I find out and access the `Method` that was passed to the function using the above `game` field which is a lambda?

I can see the `Method` while debugging on Intellij, but not sure on how to access it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access and use it through reflection as a *declaredField*  having `$method` name, as follows:

```
val methodField = game.javaClass.getDeclaredField("\$method")
val method = methodField.get(game) as Method
println(method.invoke(Game("Pietro"))) // outputs the String "Pietro"
```

Comment: Some explanation: The value of `game` in Java is essentially an anonymous class that captures a reference to `method`, so `method` should be one of the fields of the anonymous class, except it is implicit so its name is `$method`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @PietroMartinelli. I needed to know if reflection is the only way out for this?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Tenfour04. So reflection is the only way to get the method field? The caveat would be if the `method` field's name is refactored, then the code with getting the field with `$method` would not work.

Comment: You could use `getDeclaredFields().first()!!`. Since you know there’s exactly one, this is safe, but if you change the number of arguments you could be in trouble.